# "Обвести вокруг пальца" — происхождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

Подбирала синонимы к слову "облапошить" и вспомнила поговорку "обвести вокруг пальца". А откуда она пошла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обвести вокруг пальца – ловко обмануть, перехитрить кого-л. Существует несколько версий происхождения этого оборота:

1. Выражение возникло на основе оборота вокруг пальца (около пальца) обмотать 'сделать дело скоро и споро' (В. И. Даль). Быстрый и ловкий обман здесь сравнивается с быстрым наматыванием нитки на палец.
2. Очевидно, от жульничества базарных иллюзионистов. Фокусник брал у зрителей какой-либо предмет и обводил им вокруг пальца, отвлекая их внимание. В это время его сообщники очищали карманы зрителей.
3. Разбойники верили, что рука мертвеца хорошо усыпляет. Поэтому они носили с собой отрубленную руку и обводили ею вокруг спящих, чтобы те не проснулись и не помешали грабежу.
4. Выражение – калька с немецкого, в его основе – образ безвольного человека, которого можно полность подчинить – с такой же легкостью, с какой вокруг пальца обматывают (обводят) нитку или травинку.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно признанной этимологии, как ни странно, не существует.

По Интеренету ходит множество версий - от обручального кольца (якобы из Даля, хотя у него такого я не видел), до иллюзионистов, включая уголовноных.  Мне эти версии не совсем нравятся. Еще менее нравится истории с отрубанием рук и пальцев на обереги. Привожу две наиболее на мой взляд правдоподобные.

~1. От способа завязывания нитки. Весьма характерно, если присмотреться. Как вариант - наматывания той же нитки с прикрепленным грузом на палец.
~2. От тоже весьма характерного жеста покручивания пальцем с целью привлечения внимания.

смотрите еще [тут](http://www.gramota.tv/contestwork.php?id=1012&mode=t).

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, выражение означает "заставить сделать глупость, особенно себя при этом не утруждая". Дураку показывается чистый палец, абсолютно всё на виду, и тем не менее он оказывается обманутым.

Наматывание нитки: а при чём здесь нитка?

Что касается вокзально-базарных иллюзионистов, умельцев играть в напёрсток, то к ним скорее относится выражение "обманули дурака на четыре кулака".

IMHO :)